# UICollectionViewLayout Not Resizing UIImageViews Within Cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

My collectionview images are not getting resized.  I'm using the following in the viewcontroller that contains the collectionview, and it sizes correctly when the cells are empty; however with an imageview inside it doesn't behave properly.

Thanks!

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let noOfCellsInRow = 2
    let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    let totalSpace = flowLayout.sectionInset.left
        + flowLayout.sectionInset.right
        + (flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing * CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow - 1))
    let size = Int((collectionView.bounds.width - totalSpace) / CGFloat(noOfCellsInRow))
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your ViewController

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

And in `Storyboard` check if the collection view - `Estimate Size` is set to `None` in `Size Inspector`

Comment: Tried; didn't seem to change the issue.

Comment: In storyboard check if the collection view - `Estimate Size` is set to `None` in Size Inspector

Comment: That was it; thank you!  Why did that change things?

Comment: @moosgrn happy to help, unfortunately I don't have the explication for this

Comment: For what it's worth I don't know if the .invalidateLayout() did much, but the Estimate Size definitely did.  Thanks!